# Thermodynamics: Deriving inner energy from ideal gas equation of state

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

If we know equation of state for ideal gas $ PV  = NkT$ where $P$ stands for pressure, $V$ for volume, $N$ for number of particles, $k$ is Boltzmann constant and $T$ is temperature, how can one calculate the inner energy of ideal gas $ E = \frac{3}{2}NkT$ using only thermodynamic relations, that is first and second law combined into $dE = TdS - pdV$ and some of Maxwell relations?

Comment: there is a question(4th line) "how can one calculate the inner energy of ideal gas"

Comment: So, highlight it; no question mark; the title is dull. I would suggest to modify your question.

Comment: is it now better?

Comment: You cannot derive $E=3/2 NT$ from thermodynamics. In fact, $E=5/2 NT$ for diatomic gases. The best you can do is proving $E$ does not depend on $V$. Then if you assume $C_v$ is constant, you get $E=C_v N T$.